# Programming Efficiency

Tags: java, performance

I have a more or less completed Java game. Enemies spawn from the top of the screen and you fight them with your units at the bottom of the screen. The game uses up a lot of CPU, and I think it's partially because every time an enemy spawns, it has a thread with it. When it dies, the memory space that is the enemy is not removed, and neither is the thread destroyed. What I'm asking is, will deleting the enemy increase efficiency, and if it does, how? Also, do you guys have any other ways to increase efficiency?

Comment: can show us small snippets of code? why doesn't the thread stop after the enemy is dead ?

Comment: "Other ways to increase efficiency" depends entirely on how you've coded your game. There's not a lot of super general optimisations you can do. There's a [couple of settings](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/performance/jvm-tuning.xtp) you can change on the client side if memory or stack limits are an issue (but they shouldn't be).

Comment: we have nothing to go on here.

Comment: Well for one, having each 'enemy' in its own thread doesn't sound like a very good design. Read up on sprites and how to animate them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is a [profiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29).

You need to take the guesswork out of why your program is running slow. You may end up wasting a lot of time cleaning up your thread allocation only to discover it's was not the performance bottleneck after all.

There's are different profilers available in Java and the one you end up using will probably depend on your programming environment. Personally, I develop using the Netbeans IDE, which comes with a good [profiler](http://profiler.netbeans.org/) that I would recommend. If you develop using the Eclipse IDE, there's [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) and for more options see this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713940/eclipse-java-profiler

Comment: Thanks, I'll use the NBeans profiler.

Answer (score 3):

Well, games are not usually developed using those methods!

The first thing you need to do is to get rid of all the threads you create and destroy, in games we usually have only one active thread. I know, it's nice to use full features of multicore CPU but that's for experts. as an indie developer myself and knowing the performance my games need to run, I use thread only for blocking calls. like waiting for a network packet to arrive.

Now knowing that you only need one active thread, here is what games usually do!

- check for user inputs
- update scene
- render a frame

And the games cycles through the same cycle over and over. Note that many monitors don't refresh with frequencies higher than 60Hz and if they do I don't know anyone who can actually notice that! So having your game rendering with more than 60fps is just a waste of processing power. The same thing goes for checking for user inputs, and update scene. if user doesn't get any new data from the game, he can't response; so checking for inputs doesn't really make a difference! The same thing goes for the "update scene" part. if user didn't do anything new, and we aren't going to draw anything why do we care what's happening in the world? We can just let all the changes pile up and then apply them in one big update. Here I'm talking a fps limit which is usually implemented in all games to prevent computational power abuse. Either if it's CPU or GPU, having too many calculations will lead to higher power consumption, which is not well-rewarded by mobile or laptop users!

You mentioned there are some AI in your game. As you can guess any thing interacting with game has two obvious steps!

1. Observe gamestate
2. Make an Action

We can pack the whole thing up in a `think()` method. considering that these `think` calls don't consume too much time, we can call them for all non-human thinking things in the game and the best place to make these calls is when you check for user inputs. At least they can be considered as users, except computer is thinks for them and they are doomed to be beaten by an skilled gamer! it doesn't matter if these so called AI agents need to communicate. let them talk with each other as much as they like but only while they are Observing the game.

As Tim suggested using profilers is a good thing to find where your game's bottleneck is. But it might nut always be useful. Sometimes you find out there is a problem with a part of your code which is implemented is good as it can be. in these cases don't freak out! If you get stuck in such a case you can just do those stuff once per two or three frames; it's no big deal! Just check in the end if the game is running flawlessly.

Just one last note: remember you are developing a game. If you are going to implement an spring for some reason you don't need to calculate forces and velocities just as you do in a physics simulation, a simple `sin` function will do the trick! and these tricks sometimes are better than the actual proven methods. in a game users love to see the best outcome, but almost nobody cares if everything is implemented as newton stated!